# ConcurrentModificationException on List.equals()

Tags: java, exception, collections

I have a single-thread program, and a class `Grid`, which contains a `List` of `Sheet` objects, where `Sheet` can be a list or `Row`. The `Row` object is a `List` of `Value`.

I created `hashCode()` and `equals()` method using Eclipse defaults. In some cases, like when I try to put a `Grid` in a `HashMap`, I get:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1231)
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.listIterator(ArrayList.java:1091)
at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:299)
at java.util.AbstractList.equals(AbstractList.java:519)
at com.informatica.atlantic.grid.Sheet$Row.equals(Sheet.java:174)
at java.util.AbstractList.equals(AbstractList.java:523)
at com.informatica.atlantic.grid.Sheet.equals(Sheet.java:459)
at java.util.AbstractList.equals(AbstractList.java:523)
at com.informatica.atlantic.common.utils.AList.equals(AList.java:55)
at com.informatica.atlantic.grid.Grid.equals(Grid.java:152)
at com.informatica.atlantic.grid.GridData.equals(GridData.java:76)
at java.util.HashMap.getNode(HashMap.java:571)
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
```

I'm not using `iterator.remove()` or anything like it. I do have, however, lists that are actually sublist of other `List`, and are shared amongst a few `Grid` objects.

So:

1. What happens? Why is there a problem when I iterate in read-only, without any threads?
2. How do I start debugging it?

Comment: Why don't  you post your code

Comment: Well, despite your denials, this error means you're trying to modify one of your lists at the same time as you're iterating through it.

Comment: Check to see if any bundle is using an iterator. You can get a `ConcurrentModificationException` without using `remove()`. See here: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html

Comment: @passion - my code is spread around dozens of files.